# Python while loop to keep adding the squares until the sum is greater or equal to 10000

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I would like to write a while loop to keep adding the squares of consecutive integers starting from 1 (inclusive) until the sum is greater or equal to 10000 in python.Then print the integer and the sum when the condition is satisfied for the first time. Here is what I have but the code does not work.

```
total = 10000
i = 0
ger = 0

while i <= total:
  ger += i**2
print(ger)
print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to increment `i` in each loop iteration. Also, your condition is not correct: you need to compare `ger` (the sum of squares) to `total`.

```py
while ger <= total:
  ger += i**2
  i += 1
```

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.